# Azure ForEach Activity with GetMetadata and Set Variable Pipeline Expression Builder

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to fetch the directory with subfolders in azure ADF with ForEach activity. inside activity i am calling the GetMetaData activity to get Set Variable activity to do the index value. please help me, how to handle in Pipeline expression builder. please find below my sequence of the pipeline.

> setVariable -->Lookup(db connect)-->forEach(inside) -->
> Getmetadata-->setVariable.

inside Set Variable, we are trying to loop the getmetadata but always taking first index, how do we do the dynamically.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

expression builder code:

```
@activity('GetParentFolderMetadata').output.childItems[0]['name']
```

if I give above one expression, it's always taking first record, how do we get all the index.

Comment: Do you want to get the file name in the folder in a set variable in each iteration of ForEach right? correct me if I am wrong. Also can you provide what are the values that you are passing to ForEach from lookup and expected result with a sample example?

Comment: I am fetching folder path and sub path, the lookup give particular path and remain path date yyyy/mm/dd(timestamp), so that i am passing value to getmetadata to fetch the subfolder path dynamically.

Comment: getmetdata input    : {
    "dataset": {
        "referenceName": "raw_adls",
        "type": "DatasetReference",
        "parameters": {
            "container_name": "cname",
            "path": "container/folder/",
            "p_date": "2023-02-03"
        }
    },

Comment: out put of getmetadata  : {
    "childItems": [
        {
            "name": "113054",
            "type": "Folder"
        }
    ],

Comment: each loop i will be get N number childitem

Comment: in set variable, i am getting 0 th index value but expecting, all the values with indexed

Comment: lookup value : {
    "count": 2,
    "value": [
        {
            "sid": 1,
            "sn": "escape",
            "FilePath": "cname/folder/",
            "tableName": "test1",
            "ld": "od",
            "IsActive": true,
            "LastLoadDateTime": "2023-02-22T08:52:28.507Z"
        },
        {
            "sid": 2,
            "sname": "cn2",
            "FilePath": "cnn/folder/",
            "tableName": "test2",
            "ld": "od",
            "IsActive": true,
            "LastLoadDateTime": "2023-02-22T08:52:28.51Z"
        }
    ]

Comment: So your lookup will give you folder names and Get Meta data inside ForEach will give all files in that directory? and you want to store each file name in a set variable right?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your requirement, you need two For Each activities. one to iterate the Lookup output and another for iterating each Get meta data activity output array.

But ADF does not support nested ForEach. So, use Execute pipeline activity inside first ForEach and you can use another ForEach in the child pipeline.

I have given `@item()` which is a folder name to Get Meta data activity.

[image]

Now create Execute activity and inside child pipeline create an array parameter. Give the Get meta data activity output `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems` to this parameter.

[image]

Inside child pipeline use another ForEach and pass this parameter to it.

[image]

Now, you can store each file name `@item().name` into a set variable inside this ForEach and then use it as per your requirement.

[image]

**My Result in one iteration of Execute pipeline:**

[image]